# Pasting SQL into the MySQL command line

Tags: mysql

I have an application that is defining some SQL code:

```
mySql = "SELECT     
            sq.question, 
            qs.title, 
            sq.id as question_id, 
            sq.type,
            qs.id as option_id, 
            sri.title as rankTitle,
            sri.id as rankId,
            sfi.title as formTitle,
            sfi.id as formId,
            sq.sub_type,
            sq.sort_order
FROM        survey_questions as sq 
LEFT JOIN   question_suboptions as qs
ON          sq.id = qs.question_id 
LEFT JOIN   survey_rankingitems as sri
ON          sq.id = sri.question_id
LEFT JOIN   survey_formitems as sfi
ON          sq.id = sfi.question_id
WHERE       sq.survey_id = #{@surveyId}
ORDER BY    sq.sort_order"
```

I would like to paste this code (everything between the double quotes) in the MySQL command line, change the one parameter and execute it, but I have run into an issue where for every line above MySQL will display:

> Display all 1450 possibilities? (y or n)

And then 1450 different available commands. If I remove all linebreaks and tabs then I can paste in, but that is time consuming and a pain. Is there a way that I can simply paste in the above code, edit it and then execute it as a single unit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps you could save the statement to a text file `myTest.sql`, then use the MySQL command `source myTest.sql` to run it? You could then tweak the SQL in the file, save the changes, and run it again.

Answer (score 24):

This is the default *mysql* (CLI) behavior each time the user presses the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key (*mysql* uses the underlying *readline* or *EditLine* libraries (not on Windows)).

By default, when the user requests to `use` a database,  *mysql* reads tables and fields definitions. Then, pressing the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key makes *mysql* conveniently offers completion of the current input with the known tables and fields.

However, pasting some text into *mysql* that contains TAB characters (`\t` or `0x09`) triggers the same behavior - even though no <kbd>Tab</kbd> key was actually pressed from the keyboard. And this can be annoying.

---

Two options given to *mysql* can prevent that behavior, though. My favorite is `--disable-auto-rehash`. The other one is `--quiet` or `-q`.

- `--disable-auto-rehash` to prevent database, table, and column name completion (which are not read from the database, use the `rehash` command if later on you need completion). Commands history is kept, though (retrieved via the <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>↓</kbd> keys for instance). Which is convenient.
- `--quick` or `-q` which makes *mysql* not using the *history* file and no completion (does not read the database definitions).

On Linux one may add an alias in `.bashrc` to use `--disable-auto-rehash` automatically

```
alias mysql2='mysql --disable-auto-rehash'
```

Comment: Insightful! Thanks so much. Prefer this solution to writing to a text file.

Answer (score 4):

You need to remove the line breaks and tabs. The double tab is causing it to display the `Display all 1450 possibilities? (y or n)` and the line breaks are causing it to execute early.

If it's PHP, write a little script to strip it for you:

```
echo (preg_replace("/\s+/", " ", $string));
```

Or something similar for other languages.

Answer (score 1):

[Breaking not so bad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27502149/399105) explained the cause of this problem really well.

From the question:

> If I remove all linebreaks and tabs then I can paste in, but that is time consuming and a pain.

In my case, I just replaced the tabs with spaces and I was able to paste the query just fine. The MySQL console doesn't seem to care about the newlines, just the tabs.

As a way to prevent this, most editors have a setting that will insert tabs instead of spaces when you press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key. I normally have my IDEs configured this way, but in this instance it was a query I'd copied from MySQL workbench. Conveniently, it also has a setting to use spaces instead of tabs:

*Edit* > *Preferences* > *General Editors* > check *Tab key inserts spaces instead of tabs* > *OK*